# Magento2 - How to add multiple radio option in custom payment method?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I have created a custom payment method by default single option coming on checkout page which is a name of payment method but I want to give three different option in single payment method like a **Credit card**, **Debit Card**, Etc all must be Radio Button.

How we can achieve the same? based on selected option redirect to 
payment getaways...

Comment: Sir, you need to create 2-3 different extensions for that. As Magento 2 have not this kind of functionality I think.

Comment: Can you specify what you are trying to achive?